# Golangのテストはバイナリサイズに影響するか？

Tags: go

MyMathというパッケージがあり、
以下のようなテストが`sum_test.go`に書かれているとします。

```golang
package MyMath

import (
    "testing"
)

func TestSum(t *testing.T) {
    actual := Sum(10, 20)
    expected := 30
    if actual != expected {
        t.Errorf("got %v\nwant %v", actual, expected)
    }
}
```

このTestSum関数はimportした側のバイナリサイズに影響するでしょうか？
もし影響するならばバイナリサイズへの影響を避ける手段はありますか？

Answer (score 3, accepted):

影響しません。
`_test.go`で終わるファイルは`go test`の時のみビルドされます。

http://golang.org/pkg/testing/

> To write a new test suite, create a file whose name ends _test.go that
>   contains the TestXxx functions as described here. Put the file in the
>   same package as the one being tested. The file will be excluded from
>   regular package builds but will be included when the “go test” command
>   is run.